# How to add an existing server to Liferay Developer Studio?

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-ide

When I run Liferay Developer Studio 1.6.3, the `Servers` panel is empty.

I can add a new server using the context menu, but how to add an existing Tomcat server?

Comment: Is the server setup properly to serve as a Liferay Runtime Environment? Are you trying to setup a server that you downloaded as part of a Liferay bundle?

Comment: @Origineil The server I want to use is actually the one included in Liferay Developer Studio's folder.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll need to establish a runtime environment that points to the tomcat directory you want to use. Then create a server within developer studio that uses that environment.

---

I haven't used that version, but I would assume it would be very similar.

One sequence would be to access the Liferay option in the `Preferences` dialog.

How to access the dialog using the two operating systems I've used:

- Windows: use `Window -> Preferences`
- Mac: it is under the Application menu so, `Liferay Developer Studio -> Preferences`

Selecting the option will provide the necessary links for configuration.

`Create a new Liferay runtime environment` will allow you to point to the Tomcat server folder within the developer studio directory. Additionally, there will be a checkbox to `Create a new local server`. You can select that to have the server and runtime environment synced up for you.

Otherwise you can do it manually using the `Create a new Liferay server` link which will allow you to select an existing runtime environment to sync with. The view provided by this link should be the same as provided by using the context menu and selecting `New -> Server`. Within this dialog there is also a link to `Configure runtime environments`

---

Alternatively, use the context menu and select `New -> Server` followed by `Configure runtime environments`. In the Server dialog, click Add which will yield the same dialog as `Create a new Liferay runtime environment` from above.